# How to update a single (edited) App in a compiled Android image

Tags: android

I have compiled Android source code already  (which I downloaded using GIT)
and I am being editing the source code of an Application for testing on Emulator
each time I wanna see results I have to re-Compile the source code again using 'make'
I am pretty sure that there is a way to partly-compile the image

Notes: I use Ubuntu ,and Android Eclair source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this command
`mmm packages/apps/yourApp`
or whatever the path of your APP is

Assuming that :

1. your working directory is the same of your source files (which YOU downloaded using GIT)
2. you already run these commands `source build/envsetup.sh` and `lunch 1`

Next step: to update your emulator to see your changes
Run these commands
`adb remount`
`adb sync`

Finally, an advice , [using Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) will make life easier for you